# Laravel Eloquent Save to DB Using Create - Unhelpful Error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I get a very unhelpful error when I try and insert a new record in to my db. Does anyone have any idea where to start to solve this error?

```
user_id
```

That's all it says. (This is the name of one of my required fields in the table I'm saving to but it's not very descriptive.)

For reference here's my code:

```
$data = array(
    'user_id'=>1,
    'post_type'=>'0',
    'post_title'=>'blah',
    'description'=>'blah');

//it fails on this line
$id = Post::create($data);
```

Here's what my model looks like:

```
class Post extends Eloquent{
    public static $rules = array(
        'user_id'=>'required',
        'post_type'=>'required',
        'post_title' => 'required|max:25',
        'description'=>'required'
    );

    public static function validate($data){
        return Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Tried getting rid of all relationships and validation in the model. That didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called mass-assignment in Laravel, what you need to do to get it working on your model is to set a protected array called `$guarded` to be empty. Add this to your model.

```
protected $guarded = array();
```

What this array does, it can prevent attributes to be mass-assigned with an array, if you don't want an attribute to be filled with the `Model::create()` method, then you need to specify that attribute in the `$guarded` array.

If instead you want to specify only the fillable attributes, Laravel's Eloquent also provides an array called `$fillable` where you specify only the attributes that you want to fill via the mass-assigment way.

Further reading:

Mass Assignment:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Create Method:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: Thanks @gpopoteur. I thought that mass-assignment was only with the `save()` method. E.g. `$author = new Author(Input::all(); $author->save();`

Comment: @sterfry68 with the `create` method you fill the model via mass-assigment and save the object to the database.

Comment: That worked and so you Rock! So is there an Eloquent way to insert records without mass assignment?

Comment: @sterfry68 to assing without mass assignment you need to add the attributes one by one. Ex: 
`$author = new Author();`
`$author->name = 'John';`
`$author->last_name = 'Bar';`